# LiDAR file only has first point returns

Tags: lidar, spatial-analysis, global-mapper

I am working on a LiDAR `ALS` file (provided as vertical rectified and classified as ground and unclassfied) which only has single point returns, which is strange because up until now all the ALS files I have worked with have first, second, last, first of many, second of many and so on. But `Global Mapper` shows all the points as first, last and single, Global Mapper shows all the points in these classes, it doesn't distribute the points under these classes. For example, if the total point returns are 100, it shows First = 100, Single = 100 and Last = 100. Whereas, `Fugro Viewer` picks all the points as single point returns. I don't know if this file is problematic or not (I was not involved in the acquisition process, so I don't know what and how the sensor was used). Can such a file be used for vegetation structural analysis and LAD?

Comment: Would contact the source provider. The metadata for the data should describe the sensor info.

Comment: This is a fairly common practice used to save space on servers. As you indicated, this is a first return dataset in which you can use to generate a canopy height model (aka DSM). What application are you hoping to use this dataset for?

Comment: @Aaron creating CHM, computing Individual Tree Detection (ITD) and ITD metrics from FUSION (CanopyMaxima) and lidR, stem count, Leaf Area Density (LAD) and etc. The area is a desert so most of the vegetation is shrubs, grass and seedlings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Providing first return point clouds is a fairly common practice used primarily to save space and computation time. You can use first return point clouds to generate digital surface models (DSM's) or normalized DSM's (aka canopy height model (CHM)).

Yes, you may use a first return point cloud for individual tree detection. Both FUSION and lidR have algorithms that accept CHM's. Stem count can be obtained from the individual tree segmentation output.

You may run into problems using a first return point cloud for analyses where you are trying to characterize vertical structure within the forest. Many grid metrics, for example, require multiple returns to characterize structure such as understory cover. Grid metrics are also commonly used for land cover classification, which is a limitation for first return point cloud data.